# C++ _M_range_check?

Tags: c++, permutation

I am using the program from:
http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/JohnsonTrotter.java.html
I translated it from Java into c++ and I am getting a range_check error that I am not understanding. All I know is that it is coming from the perm method. Other than that I am not sure how to fix it.

```
    static void perm(int n, vector<int> p, vector<int> pi, vector<int> dir) {

     // base case - print out permutation
     if (n >= p.size()) {
      for (int i = 0; i < p.size(); i++)
       cout << p.at(i) << " ";
      return;
     }

     perm(n+1, p, pi, dir);
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

     // swap
      cout << "(" << pi.at(n) << " " << pi.at(n) + dir.at(n) << ")" << endl;;
      int z = p.at(pi.at(n) + dir.at(n));
      p.at(pi.at(n)) = z;
      p.at(pi.at(n) + dir.at(n)) = n;
      pi.at(z) = pi.at(n);
      pi.at(n) = pi.at(n) + dir.at(n);

      perm(n+1, p, pi, dir);
     }
     dir.at(n) = -1 * dir.at(n);
    }

    static void JohnsonTrotterPermute(int N){
     vector<int> p;
     vector<int> pi;
     vector<int> dir;
     cout << "Running Johnson-Trotter Permutation, number of elements = " << N << endl;
     for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
      dir.push_back(-1);
      p.push_back(i+1);
      pi.push_back(i+1);
     }
     perm(0, p, pi, dir);
     cout << "    (0 1)" << endl;
    }

    int main(){

     int n = 3;

     //LexicographicPermute(n);

     JohnsonTrotterPermute(n);

     return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several places where the index passed to `at` can be outside the bounds of the array.  You initialization of `z`, if `pi.at(n)` is >= N-1 and `dir.at(n)` is +1.  `p.at(pi.at(n))` can also do it since you initialize the pi vector with the numbers 1 thru N.  Accessing p.at(N) will cause this problem.

You'll also want to pass in your vectors to perm as references, instead of copies.

```
static void perm(int n, vector<int> &p, vector<int> &pi, vector<int> &dir)
```